# Noob LESS/CSS "translation"

Tags: css, less

How would this code translate into CSS?

```
.header-9-sub { 
  .background { 
     background-image: url("/images/header-9.jpg"); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: http://less2css.org/

Comment: Copy & Paste the code in http://lesstester.com/ and compile it by doing Ctrl + Enter :)

Answer (score 4):

Would it not become:

```
.header-9-sub .background { 
  background-image: url("/images/header-9.jpg");
}
```

Less has it as:

```
Parent class/ID{
   *Style info Here*
  Child class/ID 1{*Style info Here*}
  Child class/ID 2{*Style info Here*}
  h1{*Style info Here*}
}
```

When it is formatted from less to CSS it becomes:

```
Parent class/ID{
*Style info Here*
}    
Parent class/ID Child class/ID 1{
*Style info Here*
}
Parent class/ID Child class/ID 2{
*Style info Here*
}
Parent class/ID h1{
*Style info Here*
}
```

Comment: That was in fact the first thing I tried. Didnt work. Will try again. Derping hard today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tool for your needs - http://less2css.org/

**Answer to the question:**

```
.header-9-sub .background {
  background-image: url("/images/header-9.jpg");
}
```

**Additional information:**

Less is a CSS pre-processor, meaning that it extends the CSS language, adding features that allow variables, mixins, functions and many other techniques that allow you to make CSS that is more maintainable, themable and extendable.

Less runs inside Node, in the browser and inside Rhino. There are also many 3rd party tools that allow you to compile your files and watch for changes.

**LESS:**

```
@base: #f938ab;

.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
}
.box-shadow(@style, @alpha: 50%) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
  .box-shadow(@style, rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha));
}
.box {
  color: saturate(@base, 5%);
  border-color: lighten(@base, 30%);
  div { .box-shadow(0 0 5px, 30%) }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  color: #fe33ac;
  border-color: #fdcdea;
}
.box div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Reference - http://lesscss.org/